# Limit test convergence (from Mathematical Methods for Physicsits)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am working through the Mathematical Methods for Physicists (Arfken) and I do not understand the solution to Exercise 1.1.1 :

> 1) Prove that if $\lim_{x\to \infty}n^p u_n = A$, $A< \infty, p> 1$ the series $\sum_1^\infty u_n$ converges.
>
> 2) Prove that if $\lim_{x\to \infty}n u_n = A$, $A>0$ the series $\sum_1^\infty u_n$ diverges.

In the solution they then state for 1) that $u_n < A/n^p$ and for 2) that $u_n > A/n$. And I do not understand how that can be stated.

The way I understand the lim and 1) it would appear that $n^pu_n$ is always greater than A, and not smaller than A.

Would be great if someone can help me understand the solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Please check out the [comparison test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_n n^p u_n = A<\infty$, then $\exists N$ such that $\forall n\ge N$ one has $ |n^p u_n- A|< \varepsilon $ for a given $\varepsilon>0$, i.e.
$$ |u_n - An^{-p}| < \varepsilon n^{-p} $$
so
$$ |u_n| \le |u_n-An^{-p}| + |A|n^{-p}< \varepsilon n^{-p} + |A|n^{-p}, $$
hence 
$$ \sum_{n} |u_n| = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |u_n| + \sum_{n=N}^\infty (\varepsilon+|A|)n^{-p} <\infty   $$ 
As for the second part if $\lim_n nu_n =A>0$, then
$$ |nu_n|>\varepsilon \quad n\geq N $$ for some $\varepsilon\in(0,A)$ and so
$$ \sum_{n} |u_n| = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |u_n| + \sum_{n=N}^\infty |u_n|>\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |u_n| + \sum_{n=N}^\infty \varepsilon/n = \infty  $$

Comment: Thanks Mick, this is super helpful. I do understand $$ |u_n - An^{-p}| < \varepsilon n^{-p} $$, which imho is different from the statement in the solutions of $$u_n < A/n^p$$ (and likewise for the second case). Maybe they were just lazy in the way they wrote it. In any case, what you wrote makes perfect sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: I guess the authors just showed the principles how to think about this

Answer (score 0):

1) Since $n^pu_n$ is convergent it is bounded.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ :

$|n^pu_n| <B (>0)$, real.

Then $|u_n| <B/n^p$.

Comparison test:

$0<\sum |u_n| < \sum B/n^p$, for  $p>1$ convergent.

2) There is a $n_0$ s.t. for $n\ge n_0:$

$nu_n >A/2 >0$(Note $u_n >0$)

Then $u_n>A/(2n)$ for $n \ge n_0.$

Comparison test:

$\sum u_n$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. Super clear!

Comment: ppl4world.A pleasure:)